# Yii2 cannot render 2nd onward index form

Tags: php, html, yii, tabs, yii2

I have a page which consist of 5 tab. 1st and 2nd tab is just normal filling form while my 3rd,4th and 5th tab is the index of other index page (which I can create update and delete the data). Below is the code for the form.

```
<?php 
use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\bootstrap\ActiveForm;
use kartik\tabs\TabsX;
use kartik\date\DatePicker;
use frontend\models\OpStates;
use frontend\models\OpContact;
use frontend\models\OpCountries;
use frontend\models\OpClient;
use frontend\models\OpUnit;
use frontend\models\OpMaintenanceCharges;
use yii\helpers\ArrayHelper;
use yii\helpers\Url;


$this->title = 'Change Profile';
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = $this->title;

?>

<div class="site-changedetails">

<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['id'=>'changedetails-form',]); ?>
  <?= TabsX::widget([
        'position' => TabsX::POS_ABOVE,
        'align' => TabsX::ALIGN_LEFT,
        'items' => [
            [
                'label'=>'Client Details',
                'content'=>
                        '<div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12">'.
                                $form->field($model, "client_code")->textInput(["maxlength" => true]).'
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12">'.
                               $form->field($model, "contact_id")->dropDownList(ArrayHelper::map(OpContact::find()->all(),'id','code')).'
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12">'.
                              $form->field($model, "unit_id")->dropDownList(ArrayHelper::map(OpUnit::find()->all(),'id','code')).' 
                            </div>
                        </div>

                       <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12">'.
                                $form->field($model, 'country_id')->dropDownList(ArrayHelper::map(OpCountries::find()->all(),'id','name'),
                                    [
                                        'prompt' => 'Select Country',
                                         'onchange' => '
                                                            $.post("index.php?r=op-states/lists&id='.'" + $(this).val(), function(data){
                                                                    $("select#opclient-states_id").html(data);
                                                            });' 
                                    ]).'
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12">'.
                                $form->field($model, 'states_id')->dropDownList(ArrayHelper::map(OpStates::find()->all(),'id','state_name'),
                                            [
                                                'prompt' => 'Select States',

                                            ]).'
                           </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6">'.
                                $form->field($model, 'city')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]).'
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-md-6">'.
                                 $form->field($model, 'postcode')->textInput().'
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                          <div class="row">
                             <div class="col-md-1 col-md-offset-11">'.
                                 Html::submitButton('Save',['class'=>'pull-right btn btn-primary','style'=>'width:70px; height:40px;','name'=>'button1']).'
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        '
            ],

            [
                'label'=>'Client Details 2',
                'content'=>
                     '  <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12">'.
                                $form->field($model, "charge_interest")->dropDownList(['Yes'=>'Yes','No'=>'No']).'
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12">'.
                                $form->field($model, 'interest_effective_date')->widget(DatePicker::classname(), [

                                            'pluginOptions' => [
                                                'autoclose'=>true,
                                                'format' => 'yyyy-mm-dd',
                                                 'todayHighlight' => true,
                                                'todayBtn' => true,
                                            ]
                                        ]).'
                            </div>
                        </div> 

                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12">'.
                                 $form->field($model, "charge_reminder")->dropDownList(['Yes'=>'Yes','No'=>'No']).'
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12">'.
                                 $form->field($model, "external_debtor_code")->textInput().'
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12">'.
                                 $form->field($model, "mailing_address1")->textInput().'
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12">'.
                                 $form->field($model, "mailing_address2")->textInput().'
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12">'.
                                 $form->field($model, "mailing_address3")->textInput().'
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12">'.
                                 $form->field($model, "mailing_address4")->textInput().'
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    '
            ],

            [
                'label'=>'Maintenance Charges',
               'content' => $this->render('//op-maintenance-charges/index', [
                                'model'=>$model,
                                'dataProviderMainCharges' => $dataProviderMainCharges,
                                ]),

            ],

            [
                'label'=>'Misc Charges',
               'content' => $this->render('//op-misc-charges/index', [
                                'model'=>$model,
                                'dataProviderMiscCharges' => $dataProviderMiscCharges,
                                ]),
            ],

            [
                'label'=>'Occupier Details',
               'content' => $this->render('//op-occupier/index', [
                                'model'=>$model,
                                'dataProviderOccupier' => $dataProviderOccupier,
                                ]),
            ],
        ]
    ]); ?>

    <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

The problem is the 1st index page is working normally. [Click to see - Working normally](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LSv0A.png)

The 2nd index page n 3rd index cannot work. The form wont even come out. The screen just become darker and I cant click anything like this [Click to see - Cant Work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yKzOS.png)

Anyone can help or have any idea on how to fix it? Thanks

Comment: Update you are code with $this->renderPartial instead of $this->render.

Comment: @Irfan Ali it show Calling unknown method: yii\web\View::renderPartial()

Comment: Yii::$app->controller->renderPartial('myview'); try this one

Comment: I can't see  your link  for img ..  you have error ?

Comment: @Irfan Ali the code ok but it still doesnt work. The 2nd form still wont come out

Comment: @scaisEdge the link ok ar. I can view the image still

Comment: but if I put 3 index page into 1 tab. It works fine